# Divide one table by another table created in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatable, mysql-workbench

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT `NeighbourhoodName`,
count(NAME) as `Number of Parks`,
sum(CASE 
    WHEN `parks`.`Advisories` = 'Y' THEN 1
    ELSE 0 
END) as Advisories,
FROM parks
GROUP BY `NeighbourhoodName`;
```

In the second line of the code, I create a column called "Number of Parks". I would like all the values in the next column (Advisories) to be divided by the values in "Number of parks". However, when I try to insert the division statement after the column like this:

```
SELECT `NeighbourhoodName`,
count(NAME) as `Number of Parks`,
sum(CASE 
    WHEN `parks`.`Advisories` = 'Y' THEN 1
    ELSE 0 
END)/`Number of Parks` as Advisories
FROM parks
GROUP BY `NeighbourhoodName`;
```

I get the following error:

```
Unknown column, `Number of Parks` in field list.
```

How can I perform this division while still keeping it in one query?

Comment: You can't use in the same select statement the alias you use to name a field, either make it a subquery or just repeat the count in the division.

Comment: I can't repeat the count in the division because the division needs to be done after the groupby statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an outer query to do the division.

```
SELECT `NeighbourhoodName`,
       `Number of Parks`,
        Advisories/`Number of Parks` as Advisories
FROM    ( SELECT `NeighbourhoodName`,
                 count(NAME) as `Number of Parks`,
                 sum( CASE  WHEN `parks`.`Advisories` = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as Advisories
          FROM parks
          GROUP BY `NeighbourhoodName`
         ) as tbl;
```

[Problems with Column Aliases](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)

> An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a
> different name. You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING
> clauses to refer to the column.

Answer (score 0):

Or use the expression of `count(Name)` instead of `Number of Parks`:

```
select NeighbourhoodName,
       count(Name)      as `Number of Parks`,
       sum(case when Advisories='Y' then 1 else 0 end)
       /count(Name)     as Advisories
  from parks
 group by NeighbourhoodName;
```

Comment: That doesn't work because the counting is done during the group-by.

Comment: @imad97 It works in MySQL 8.0.26. Maybe you run it in earlier version?